# synchronized access is slow

Tags: java, java-threads

I share a list between many thread.
All the data needed by the thread are there before they start, I don't add any other value to the list.
Each tread take a value in list, value is removed from the list and there is a distant call done.
This block is synchronized.

```
    while (!contactList.isEmpty()) {

        Contact contact = null;

        synchronized (contactList) {

            if (!contactList.isEmpty()) {

                contact = contactList.get(0);
                contactList.remove(0);
            }
        }
        //call the service with contact
    }
```

Is there a more efficient way to do the job?

For the moment, it's faster to take all contact and split them to many individual program.

Comment: Do you care about getting anything from *any other spot* in the list besides the first entry?

Comment: `remove(0)` will shift all the remaining elements of the list to left. Removing the last element is one way of improving it.

Comment: so i could read last element and removing it.

Comment: How do you conclude that the sychronized access is the problem? From the small code excerpt I would presume its *unlikely* synchronization causes any noticeably performance impact here. More likely that remove(0) is to blame (for ArrayList that a O(N) complexity operation).

Answer (score 3):

If you genuinely only want to pull elements from the front of your list and you want to be sure that they're there, then you should look into a [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) instead.  This also guarantees O(1) insertion and removal, since insertion occurs at the end of the queue, and retrieval occurs at its head without the need to shift elements down.

Because you state that the data exists prior to entering this block, a call to `poll` will only return `null` if the list itself is empty. From there, you'd have to decide what it means to return `null` from the queue.

A (very rough) example:

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Contact> contactQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
Contact contact = contactQueue.poll(); // will return null if empty
```

Comment: thread don't add value, it's just i don't want thread take the same value, that why i put a synchronisez block and a i remove the value.

Comment: Okay, so if the data's already there before you get to this block of code (somehow), then there's a different data structure that can be used.

Comment: just want to take a value for a datastructure and don't take same from many thread...

Comment: I've revised my answer.  You can use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` which accomplishes the same thing without any blocking.

Comment: any need to synchronized the block?

Comment: No.  `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is thread safe.  You don't have to synchronize anything by hand when using it.

Comment: if (!contactList.isEmpty()) {  
  System.out.println(contactList.size());  
  contactList= contactList.poll();  
}   with this code, same value is something displayed many time..